# AngularJS TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror, angular-filters

Getting a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.
The code is meant to filter a list by the tags that it contains. I had the code working for a single tag but now that the query is an array of tags it's not working.

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.query = "";    

        $scope.formData.list = [{"Tags":["a", "b", "c"]}, {"Tags":["a", "b"]}, {"Tags":["b", "c"]}]    

        $scope.filterTags = function(query){
            return function(elem){
                query = query.split(",");    

                for(i in query){    

                    if(elem.Tags.indexOf(query[i]) == -1){
                        return false;
                    }

                }    

                return true;
            };

        }    

    });
```

And the template.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model='formData.query' />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='item in formData.list | filter:filterTags(formData.query)'>{{item.Tags}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have one line in the wrong place. The line is:

```
query = query.split(",");
```

It should be before the `return function(elem)` line so you don't split it every time. But more importantly, it's because that line changes `query` from being a *string* to being an *array*. And arrays don't have a `.split()` method. Hence the "*undefined is not a function*" error. :-)

Updated JS code:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.query = "";    

        $scope.formData.list = [{"Tags":["a","b","c"]},{"Tags":["a","b"]},{"Tags":["b","c"]}]    

        $scope.filterTags = function(query){
            query = query.split(",");    
            return function(elem){
                for(var i in query){    
                    if(elem.Tags.indexOf(query[i]) == -1){
                        return false;
                    }
                }    
                return true;
            };
        }    
    });
```